# Ramification points of projection to y-line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Rick Miranda's "Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces" chapter 2, lemma 4.6 says that:

> Let $X$ be a smooth projective plane curve defined by a homogeneous polynomial $F(x,y,z) = 0$; consider the map $G: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ defined by $G[x:y:z] = [x:z]$. Then $G$ is ramified at $p \in X$ if and only if $(\partial F/\partial y)(p) = 0$.

I understand that for point where either $x$ or $z$ is nonzero this theorem is true by looking at the affine parts and then considering local charts.  This only leaves the point [0:1:0] which might very well be a point in $X$.  But the map $G$ is not even defined there. Is there something missing here?

More generally, we know that for a curve $X$, ratio of two homogeneous polynomials $P,Q$ such that the denominator does not identically vanish on $X$ gives a meromorphic function, and therefore gives a holomorphic map to Riemann sphere $\mathbb{P}^1$ as $[P : Q]$. But for the points where both $P$ and $Q$ vanish, this map is not even defined?  What is going on?  Can I not write the  meromorphic function defined by $P/Q$ as $[P:Q]$ globally?  It seems to me that at points where both $P$ and $Q$ vanish I can simplify the function locally so that it either has a pole or a removable singularity. For a trivial example consider $P = Q = x$ and then $P/Q$  is just the constant function 1, but it still doesn't make sense to write $[x:x]$ because it won't be defined at points $x = 0$, assuming there is such a point on $X$.

Comment: The rational map $\Bbb{P^1\to P^1}$, $f([x:1]) = [x:x]$ is a morphism on $\Bbb{P^1}-[0:1]$, but it extends in an obvious way to a morphism on the whole of $\Bbb{P^1}$ (sending every point to $[1:1]$), and this is that extension that you need to consider. It works the same way for $G([x:y:z]) = [x:z]$ (when restricted to a smooth curve).

Answer (score 3):

The result you're looking for here is that any rational map from a smooth curve $C$ to a projective variety $P$ extends uniquely to an honest morphism $C\to P$. This is known (in some places, at least) as the curve-to-projective extension theorem, and here's an outline of the proof: it suffices to prove the fact in the case when $C$ is affine and our map is defined on $C\setminus \{x\}$. Then our rational map $C\to P$ is specified by $c\mapsto [f_0(c):f_1(c):\cdots:f_n(c)]$ where the $f_i$ are rational functions on $C$. Since $\mathcal{O}_{C,x}$ is a DVR, we can divide through by an appropriate power of the uniformizer to arrange that none of the $f_i$ have a pole at $c$ and not all of the $f_i$ vanish at $c$, giving an honest map $C\to P$ extending our rational morphism. For a full accounting, see section 16.5 in Vakil's [Foundations of Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf).

---

In the comments, some clarification regarding what happens in the case that $[0:1:0]$ is on our curve was requested. First, if $[0:1:0]$ is on $V(F)$, then $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}([0:1:0]) =0$: if $\deg F = 1$, then $F$ is the linear equation $ax+bz$ for some $a,b\in k$; while if $\deg F \geq 2$ then every term in $F$ is divisible by either $x$ or $z$ and the same is true for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$, so it must evaluate to zero.

Now I claim that the image of $[0:1:0]$ under the projection is $\left[\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}([0:1:0]):\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}([0:1:0])\right]$, where it is clear that the map on tangent spaces is zero, so the projection is ramified at $[0:1:0]$. Up to a linear change of coordinates preserving $[0:1:0]$, we may assume the tangent line to $C$ at $[0:1:0]$ is just $V(x)$. Dehomogenize by setting $y=1$: up to scaling, we can write $F=x(1+p(x))-zq(x,z)$ where $q$ has vanishing constant term. Then $$[x:z]=[x(1+p(x)):z(1+p(x))]= [zq(x,z):z(1+p(x))] = [q(x,z):1+p(x)]$$ which evaluates to $[0:1]$ when we set $x=z=0$. So the projection map is ramified at $[0:1:0]$ when that point is on our curve.

Comment: Well, if $[0:1:0]$ is on your curve, then either the projection map is constant, or the map *does* ramify at $[0:1:0]$, because the map on tangent spaces from $[0:1:0]$ to $f([0:1:0])$ is zero. This is exactly what you'd expect, as $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}([0:1:0])=0$ if $[0:1:0]$ is on your curve.

Comment: I just saw your comment.  Sorry I had deleted my comment soon after posting it in hopes of figuring it out on my own, but I couldn't.  Thank you for answering.  The question was that Miranda implicitly assumes that the point [0:1:0] won't be a ramification point, why is that?  I see that partial w.r.t. y has to be zero, but I don't how to conclude the claim on tangent spaces...

Comment: If I proceed simply by looking at the chart y = 1, and suppose $\partial F/\partial  z ([0:1:0])\neq 0$ then $z$ is locally given by a function $g(x)$ (which vanishes at $0$). Then the projection  is given by $h(x) = g(x)/x$ which has a removable singularity at x = 0 because g vanishes at x=0, but I don't how to proceed from here to conclude that $h'(0) = 0$ which will show that it is ramified at the origin (origin on y =1 chart corresponds to out original point).

Comment: I also had a question about the curve to projective extension theorem: I know that maps to $P^n$ are given by global sections of a line bundle, but why do these section correspond to rational functions of $C=\text{Spec}A$ in case of $C - \{x\}$?

Comment: Second question first - we take care of that in the reduction. Pick an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ so that $\mathcal{L}$ is trivial on $U-p$, then the sections are functions on $U-p$ or rational functions on $U$. Up to shrinking $U$ without removing $p$, we may assume that $U$ is affine and work with it instead. I'll deal with the other question in an edit to my post and ping you when that's handled.

Comment: @student I worked through the case where $[0:1:0]$ is on our curve in an edit to the question.